# Have 2 @-webkit-keyframes in 1 css

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have 2 @-webkit-keyframes on 1 css? Like

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse_one{
                0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
                30% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
                40% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.08); }
                50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); background-color: #b81900; }
                60% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
                70% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); }
                80% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
                100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
            }

@-webkit-keyframes pulse_two{
                0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
                30% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
                40% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.08); }
                50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); background-color: #eea236; }
                60% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
                70% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); }
                80% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
                100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
            }

#pulseOne
            {
                -webkit-animation-name: 'pulse_one';
                -webkit-animation-duration: 5000ms;
                -webkit-transform-origin:70% 70%;
                -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
            }

#pulseTwo
            {
                -webkit-animation-name: 'pulse_two';
                -webkit-animation-duration: 5000ms;
                -webkit-transform-origin:70% 70%;
                -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
            }
```

I got the error saying "Unexpected token WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_SYM found". But my 2 animation above works perfectly fine on my page. Im just curious and its kinda bug me a little when have a red line on my code. Any help is apreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Multiple keyframe definitions should work perfectly. Where do you get this error?

Comment: And FYI any CSS rules with vendor prefixes (such as `-webkit-`) is considered invalid by most validators, even though they should work as expected in the targeted browser.

Comment: im using netbeans 8.0. Well its working perfectly fine on my loaded page. Its just bugs me a little when i see red line in my code. Hehe..  Actually im just curious..